# How can I fetch a relationship in Core Data swift

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, fetch, iosdeployment

This is my core data model:

[image]

I have two Entities: `Folder <->> Note` and I want to fetch all the notes in a folder.

Answer (score 13):

First of all it's recommended to name the *many* relationship as plural (`notes`), that makes it easier to understand the model.

If you have a `NSManagedObject` subclass and a reference to a folder just get the notes by the relationship:

```
let notes = folder.notes
```

However this returns a `Set`. If you want an array write

```
let notes = folder.notes.allObjects as! [Note]
```

You can also use a predicate to be assigned to a fetch request on the `Note` entity:

```
let name = "Foo"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"folder.name == %@", name)
```

Comment: this is the first quesiton i post on stack and it recommend me to not to put thank you but Thakssss! haha

Answer (score 2):

Write these line of code in your func

```
let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = container.viewContext
        let request:NSFetchRequest<Notes> = Notes.fetchRequest()


  request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "here write relationship name .folderName = %@" , searchbar.text!)
        }
        do
        {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            for notes in result 
{
....
}

}
```